# Postman sending null values to spring login

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, postman

I am having a problem which is that postman is sending null values to my login.
When I try it in browser, everything seems fine, yet when I try it out on the postman desktop app, I get a variety of things
Either 401, 200, or 301. 401 directly doesn't send any data, as if my postman post didn't exist. 200 and 301 it sends data, but null values (which I don't know how to fix)
I tried changing the login to basic spring login, using the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, reading stack overflow posts (most of the people with the same problem as me had some sort of typo in the code that was making them blow up), also securityFilterChain according to SpringDocs, etc.

I am currently using a custom auth to fetch the info from my DB (although I think it is not necessary at all, since I proved without this class and it worked fine)

So anyways, first of all here's the postman request I am using to try to login

[image]

Also, this too, because I had to try to see if it worked although it's the same

[image]

And here's the code related to the security

Here is my UserDetailsService class:

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
   UserDTO user = this.getUserByUsername(username);
    return  MHelpers.modelMapper().map(user,UserPrincipal.class);
}
```

LoginConfiguration ( I know WebSecurityConfigurer is deprecated, I was just testing things out, with securityFilterChain the result doesn't change. In fact if I comment out this LoginConfig class, I get 401 Unauthorized and don't know how to fix it.)

```
@Configuration
public class LoginConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic().and().formLogin().permitAll().and().csrf().disable().cors().disable();
    }
```

UserPrincipal.class

```
@Data
public class UserPrincipal implements Serializable, UserDetails{
    int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Date accountCreationDate = new Date(); 


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I can't seem to find the mistake, I would like some insight or help if somebody had this issue and knows how to solve it or maybe tell spring boot to authorize postman if it's being blocked by the security.
It's a basic username and password auth.

I also tried this:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers( "/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .permitAll();

}
```

but it returned 302 (when I have automatic redirect enable, probably because postman cannot redirect to HAL explorer). My idea is for spring to handle the security and then later using react and axios do a fetch api with the username and password and bring/post the data I need.

The stack trace:

```
backend.Exceptions.NotFoundException: User not found
    at backend.services.UserServiceImpl.getUserByUsername(UserServiceImpl.java:115) ~[classes/:na]
    at backend.services.UserServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserServiceImpl.java:160) ~[classes/:na]
    at backend.services.UserServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$831e0214.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.invokeMethod(CglibAopProxy.java:386) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.access$000(CglibAopProxy.java:85) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:704) ~[spring-aop-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at backend.services.UserServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9a4b6ede.loadUserByUsername(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at backend.services.CustomAuthProvider.authenticate(CustomAuthProvider.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:201) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.4.jar:5.7.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.3.jar:5.7.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.68.jar:9.0.68]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I know the problem is in this method, probably, because it is receiving a null value. The problem is that postman is sending those null values because on browser the auth works fine

```
public UserDTO getUserByUsername(String username) {
            User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
            if(user == null) {
                throw new NotFoundException("User not found");
            }
            return convertToUserDTO(user);
        }
```

Edit 1: This may sound stupid but I don't have a login controller because as far as I understand, spring handles it? Somebody correct me if I am wrong, but if it's not that spring's default controller is failing then I don't know what is causing the issue of the values being sent with null

Edit 2: It works with url-encoded, however I want basic auth AND form login, and the problem comes when I try to log in via json / basic auth. There, the null values start appearing.

Comment: Add the following and let me know what you'll get:
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")

Comment: Same error, still passing null values. What it's throwing is my custom exception of 'UserNotFound' since,as there is no null value in the DB, then the find of the db returns null.

The stack trace is the same as posted on the original post. I am thinking it could be spring's controller and it would be necessary to override it, but I can't assure it is. What do you think?

Comment: Add breakpoints and methods to print each value in the console. getUserByUsername() may be the cause of the problem. If you see user record in the database interface, use userRepository.findAll() to be sure that it's related to the same database you mentioned. If it works as expected, then it means the problem is about the findByUsername()

Comment: As your question is not well written, it's hard to detect the problem in one touch.

Comment: I am sorry. What info do you need me to give you in order to help me debug the issue?
Also, I already did the printing issue. From the get-go, the value is passed as null. I have this query of findUserByUsername, which I let spring define for me, however I tried defining my own SQL query using @Query(Select u from Users u where u.username = :username) but it didn't work either. 
The thing is that if the method failed, then the web auth wouldn't work either (my guess). So it has to be something related to the controller, that's what I am led to think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no reply was given, I'll leave the code that worked for me to put basic auth as well as form login. Any other order or solution proved to be not working. This solves the 'null values' of the postman basic auth, although I cannot pass the values as a JSON (because those get passed as null)

```
  @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                csrf().disable().httpBasic().and().formLogin().permitAll().and().
                cors().
                configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues()); 
        return http.build();
    }
```